# How do I compile a groovy user entered script at runtime

Tags: groovy

I want to compile and execute a piece of Groovy that the user types in (in a DSL) at runtime. Is this possible in Groovy? And if so what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GroovyClassLoader:

```
def userScript = '''
  (1..5).each {
    println 'X' * it
  }
'''

Class c = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass( userScript )
c.newInstance().run()
```

Or you can use any of the other methods in the [documentation for integrating Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html#_groovy_integration_mechanisms).

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use the concept of binding in groovy which helps you to inject variables from outside and process them.

http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2010/08/groovy-goodness-store-closures-in.html